# Binary I/O Stream

Tags: java, io, javafx, random-access

I have two programs. One that outputs some information:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;

public class Output {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException,
            IOException {

        int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

        // Create an output stream for binary file
        try (ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream("Exercise7_05.dat", true));) 
        {
            // Write to each type to the file
            output.writeDouble(5.5);
            output.writeObject(numbers);
            output.writeObject(new java.util.Date());
            output.writeUTF("Exercise7_05.dat");
        }
    }
}
```

And the other that is supposed to read the binary input and print it to the console:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;

public class Input {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException,
            IOException {

        /*
         * Create an input stream for binary file to be converted to something
         * readable
         */
        try (ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(
                new FileInputStream("Exercise7_05.dat"));) {

            // Read each object from binary file
            double doubleValue = input.readDouble();
            System.out.println("Double value: " + doubleValue);

            int[] newNumbers = (int[]) (input.readObject());
            System.out.println("Integers: " + Arrays.toString(newNumbers));

            Date date = (java.util.Date) (input.readObject());
            System.out.println("DateTime: " + date);

            String fileName = input.readUTF();
            System.out.println("File name: " + fileName);
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that I get an error when I try to run the input stream:

"Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Exercise7_05.dat (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
    at application.Input.main(Input.java:18)"

Comment: My guess is that you're running them from different directories.

Comment: I'm new to all this, so what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Well your code tries to read a file from whatever directory it's running in. If you ran the code to *write* the file from a different directory, then it won't be able to find the file - which would explain the exception you're getting.

Comment: How do I go about getting my program to input from the write directory?

Comment: Well you haven't told us *anything* about how you're running this code, which makes it very hard to help you.

Comment: Oh, of course. I'm using eclipse and saving each program in the same workspace but in different projects (hence two programs).

Comment: Right, so you can edit the run configuration to say where to execute. Or just run from the command line in the same directory. Or embed an absolute filename in the program.

Comment: I got it figured out. I just copied and pasted the .dat file to the necessary folder.